# Does Spark schedule workers on the same nodes where the data resides?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

The Google MapReduce paper said that workers were scheduled on the same node as the data resided, or at least on the same rack if that was possible. I haven't read through the entire Hadoop documentation, but I assume that it moves the computation to the data if possible, rather than the data to the computation.

(When I first I learned about Hadoop, all data from HDFS to the workers had to go through a TCP connection, even when the worker was on the same node as the data. Is this still the case?)

In any event, with Apache Spark, do workers get scheduled on the same nodes as the data, or does the RDD concept make it harder to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking it depends. Spark recognizes multiple levels of locality (including `PROCESS_LOCAL`, `NODE_LOCAL`, `RACK_LOCAL`) and tries to schedule tasks to achieve the best locality level. See [Data Locality](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-locality) in [Tuning Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html)

Exact behavior can be controlled using `spark.locality.*` properties. It includes amount of time scheduler waits for free resources before choosing a node with a lower locality. See [Scheduling](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#scheduling) in [Spark Configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).